# Return empty body with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I specify sinatra to return an empty body with status of 200?

I can do `body ""` but is there a more explicit way of doing this?

Comment: Why? Try `halt 200`, no need to set a body.

Comment: @iain if you make it an answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: @Nakilon Your wish is my command :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Using the Rack interface

From the [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Return%20Values):

> You can return any object that would either be a valid Rack response, Rack body object or HTTP status code:
>
> - An Array with three elements: [status (Fixnum), headers (Hash), response body (responds to `#each`)]
> - An Array with two elements: [status (Fixnum), response body (responds to #each)]
> - An object that responds to `#each` and passes nothing but strings to the given block
> - A Fixnum representing the status code

So returning either of

1. `[200, {}, ['']]`
2. `[200, ['']]`
3. `['']`
4. `200`

should do the trick.

### Using helpers

In [Setting Body, Status Code and Headers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Setting%20Body,%20Status%20Code%20and%20Headers), the helper methods `status` and `body` (and `headers`) are introduced:

```
get '/nothing' do
  status 200
  body ''
end
```

Comment: How does '' respond to #each?

Comment: what is the difference between halt and status?

Comment: [`status`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/4e92d604/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L229-L233) just sets the return code, [`halt`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/4e92d604/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L936-L941) terminates the request processing.

Comment: you can also use `status :ok`

Answer (score 10):

Also from the [docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Halting):

> To immediately stop a request within a filter or route use:
>
> halt
>
> You can also specify the status when halting:
>
> halt 410

So in the case where you only need a `200` status it would be:

```
halt 200
```

`halt` is one of the most useful methods Sinatra makes available to you, worth reading the docs for. I often use it to return error messages early in processing a route, for example when required params are missing.